# Missing worker processes in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, application-pool, worker-process

I have a weird problem. I have an app pool and a web site hosted in that app pool. It was all fine just a while ago before I made some changes to my web site code. Now I can see the App Pool in the App Pools tab but there is no corresponding Worker Process in the Worker Processes view. My App Pool and the website are both running. I have tried IISRESET obviously but it has not worked. Neither has re-publishing the web site. I am stumped. Can anyone help?

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: I am trying to attach to the w3wp process in Visual Studio. For that i need the worker process id.

Comment: The worker process shows up when a request is made so if it's not showing load up the website and it should show